# How to create a new repository on Github from Magit

Tags: magit, github

I am unable to add a remote repo to github if it does not already exist on github.

E.g.
  `magit-init`
  Add some files, stage and commit.

Then `magit-remote-add` --> `Remote name:github` --> `Remote url: https://github.com/username/repoName.git`

This fails with:

```
Updating github
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/userName/repoName.git/' not found
error: Could not fetch github
```

It all works fine if go to github.com and create the new repo there first, but this is an extra step. I'm wondering how can I create a new repo on github directly from magit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs does not provide any direct functionality to interface with Github directly. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039562/emacs-magit-how-to-create-and-delete-repositories-on-github) by one our members. He wrote an implementation to create repo from magit.

Comment: Thanks, will give that a try at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ghub](https://github.com/magit/ghub), for example, to create a new repository named "my-cool-project", simply run:

```el
(ghub-post "/user/repos" '((name . "my-cool-project")))
```

If you want set the name of the repository to the git directory name, you can use:

```el
(when-let ((git-root (locate-dominating-file default-directory ".git"))
           (basename (file-name-nondirectory (directory-file-name git-root))))
  (ghub-post "/user/repos" `((name . ,basename))))
```

There are also many other optional parameters for creating a new repository, such as `description`, `homepage` and `private`, see https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create.

Comment: good suggestion, but does not involve magit.

Comment: @A_P that's right, since creating a new github project has nothing to do with git/magit.